# Two csProj assemblies with "same name" causing issues

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net-assembly

Simple question.

I have multiple projects e.g.

SomeDir/Common/Utils.csproj
SomeDir/Services/Common/Utils.csproj

Projects's namespace reflect folder structure, how can I add both of these utils projects as assembly to another project? Visual studio seems to complain about the name.

Comment: are they in the same namespace?

Comment: You can use alias

Comment: @Natrium same as folder structure so not entirely

Comment: both assembly has same name?

Comment: No only the project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is just editing the .csproj the UI of VS does not support loading 2 projects with the same name, editing the file is just fine.

As addition, these projects will end up in Artifactory, so then the problem will no longer persist.

Answer (score 3):

I would give my projects more descriptive names. Even though both projects are utils, there will still be a difference in what they are meant to do, or where they should be used.
An example of this descriptive naming could be:

- Common.Utils
- Services.Utils

This would adress the problem of conflicting names, and will also make it more clear to anyone reading your code.

Comment: I wouldnt even use the name Utils, but I'm not the architect :(

Comment: Talk to the architect and explain your problem and propose a solution such as this. Maybe he hasn't thought of this.